# How to join these tables in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am facing problem to join these tables and also know how to make controller code to view data in view file with text boxes.

```
public function get_order_return_info()
{
    $this->db->select('tbl_order_details.*', false);
    $this->db->select('tbl_order_details.order_details_id', false);
    $this->db->select('tbl_order.order_id', false);
    $this->db->select('tbl_product.product_id', false);
    $this->db->select('tbl_inventory.product_quantity', false);
    $this->db->from('tbl_order_details');
    $this->db->join('tbl_order', 'tbl_order_details.order_id  =  tbl_order.order_id ', 'left');
    $this->db->join('tbl_product', 'tbl_order_details.product_code  =  tbl_product.product_id ', 'left');
    $this->db->join('tbl_inventory', 'tbl_product.product_id  =  tbl_inventory.product_id ', 'left');
    $query_result = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query_result->result();
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: is the result produce single row ? or is it an array ? different result makes different solution

Comment: sorry i think this is an array

Answer (score 0):

You can use MVC to solve this

```
//Controller
function get_data() {

   $data['list'] = $this->your_model->get_data();
   $this->load->view('your_view/location',$data); 
}

//Model
function get_data() {

  $sql = "your_query";
  $list = $this->db->query($sql)->result_array();
  return $list;
}

//View
foreach($list as $data) {
  echo $data['your_selected_field']; // it could be table,text field,or just text
}
```

**API Reference : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html#result-arrays**
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

First u can create OrderModel to work with order table. Then create function get_order_data.

```
//Order Model
public function get_orders() {
   // your db query to get orders
   return $result;
}
```

Then u can load model in controller using `$this->load->model('OrderModel');` Best place is __construct to load model

And call your get_orders() function

```
// Your controller
// Create data array to store front data 
$data = [];
$data['orders'] = $this->OrderModel->get_orders();
```

After getting $orders pass it to view using following codes

```
$this->load->view('path/to/view', $data);
```

Finally u can call your order data in view using $orders

I hope this will help u

Answer (score 0):

You need to set alias to the table to function it properly  like this.

```
  $this->db->select('a.*,a.order_details_id, b.order_id ', false);
   $this->db->from('tbl_order_details as a');
    $this->db->join('tbl_order as b', 'a.order_id  =  b.order_id ', 'left');
```

If you want select 1 row only you need to use this function.

```
$this->db->get('tbl_order_details')->row_array();
```

or if you want all result row you need to use this.

```
 $this->db->get('tbl_order_details')->result_array();
```

On your controller you should add this lines to pass your result on your view page.

```
public function index()
{
        $data['orderDetails'] = $this->your_model->get_order_return_info();
        $this->load->view('pages/yourview/index',$data);
}
```

And finally to set your order details to the text boxes. You need to echo it inside the text boxes like this.

```
 <input type="Text" name="orderID" value="<?php echo $orderDetails['order_id'];?>" >
```

If you use result_array() you need to use foreach loop to echo it.